# DataSet1>DataTable1 strange error

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I created a dataset and added so a datatable with about 18 columns.
I added the datagrid and the data details on the form. Compiler show no errors.
When i run the application i get this strange error that i'm not understanding! Code show no error too, what's wrong with this table?

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   Additional Information: Unable to bind to
>   property or column Date of DataSource.

Edit: error came out when i add the datatable1 details to the form. datagridview instead give no problem
Please someone could give me tips to avoid this error. I have no idea, i found nothing on google.

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: we are not going to have any idea either because there is no code.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I still written less than 1 code line! I used only the editor to make the windows form layout and the DataSet to create the DataTable... how can i explain? In the datatable i put a column called "Reg. Date" it is giving problem?

Comment: Well now that is morning i solved the problem :) Problem was the name of the column that has a dot. Dot must be removed.